# putting div above the flash object

Tags: html, css

iam trying to put the div menu above the object tag but still under the object tag any way to put it above the flash .

```
    <div>
<div class='menu'>menu</div>
<object width="400" height="40"

classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
<param nastatime="SRC" value="bookmark.swf">
<embed src="bookmark.swf" width="400" height="40"></embed>
</object>
</div>
<style>
#menu{
width: 100%;
clear: both;
float: left;
position: relative;
background: red;
z-index: 1111111;
}

object{
float: left;
position: absolute;
z-index: -13;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to be looking at the **wmode** parameter of Flash when you're embedding your content.  The default `wmode` is `"window"` which layers the content over the top of everything else.  Set it to `"opaque"` or `"transparent"` to allow it to be layered properly.

See http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You are using class as menu but in css there is #, replace it with .Try this css

```
    <div class="main">
<div class="menu">menu</div>
<div class="fobject"><object width="400" height="40"

classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
<param nastatime="SRC" value="bookmark.swf">
<embed src="bookmark.swf" width="400" height="40"></embed>
</object>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​

    .main{
 position:relative   
}
.menu{
width: 100%;
clear: both;
float: left;
position: relative;
background: red;
z-index: 100;
}

.fobject{
float: left;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
}​
```

Comment: Hello Sowmya , i put your code but still menu under the object flash , i want menu above the flash .

Comment: Also try to use the valid code to embed the flash file (the code which u are using is not w3c valid code). You can get the valid code here http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/08/w3c-valid-code-to-embed-flash-file.html

Comment: yes u right iam tried to put wmode='direct' and itworked well thanks Somaya